# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-context

I am using adapter to show images. In Adapter, How to get context when using Picasso? 
I tried different solutions but I couldn't solve. What should I do when using picasso in Adapter? Context is a big problem for developers I see on the internet.

```
package gc.x;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import gc.ovidos_challenge.R;
import gc.ovidos_challenge.models.Image;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;


public class ImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Image> imagesList;

    private Context context;

    public ImagesAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView imageview;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageurl);

        }
    }


    public ImagesAdapter(List<Image> imagesList) {
        this.imagesList = imagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_image, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Image image = imagesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(image.title);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(image.url).into(holder.imageview);


      //  holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(image.getBitmapFromURL());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
    }


}
```

Comment: Context is not a big problem. show us the code are you using to create this ImagesAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have created two constructors one for context and one for your data. use one constructor to initialize both of them

like this

```
public ImagesAdapter(Context context,List<Image> imagesList) {
        this.context = context;
this.imagesList=imagesList;
    }
```